# Why doesn't JavaScript convert a string to an Object?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to run a list of strings through an object. When I do it individually it works, but when I pass it through as a string it doesn't work. How would I fix this?

```
// this doesn't work
var a = "IntegrationItem1";
var data = faq.a; 

// but this works
var data = faq.IntegrationItem1;
```

What's causing the first example to not work? Is the variable data seeing it as faq."IntegrationItem1" instead of faq.IntegrationItem1?

Comment: `var data = faq[a];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access properties of the object using it's names:

```
var a = "IntegrationItem1";
var data = faq[a];
```

Comment: Good documentation on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `faq["IntegrationItem1"]` => `faq[a]`